# Can any one help in the below equation , I am getting error

Tags: equations, split

```
\begin{equation}\begin{split}

\scalebox{1.5} { $\prod^{e}= \frac{1}{2} \int_{x_a}^{x_b} A_e E_e u^{T} B^T B u dx $ + {\color{blue} { $U_{ts}= \frac{1}{2} C (\frac{dw^{element 1}}{du}\Big|_{u=0})$ }} + {\color{blue}$U_s = \frac{1}{2} C (P_0)$ } -$ \int_{x_a}^{x_b} u^{T} B^T q_0 dx$} \\ 

\end{split}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please., provide a sketch, how you wish that equation will look. Sorry, your code is mess and this can not be figured out from it.

Comment: You cannot leave blank lines in math environments.

Comment: You also have `\begin{equation}` with no matching `\end{equation}`.